# Problem with Full text Searching

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am searching in resumes weather the word is exist or not

i am using the below query

Case1:

```
select top(10) c_resume_text from sntbl_candidates
where contains(c_resume_text,'"a/dm"')
```

in the above example only it is not working properly .It showing  resumes even though there is no text like that.

In Messages i am getting the following message.

Informational: The full-text search condition contained noise word(s).

if i try with

Case 2:

```
select top(10) c_resume_text from sntbl_candidates
where contains(c_resume_text,'"a/d')
```

i am getting proper results in case 2

can any one suggest me what to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question may get you what you need to know.
[Dropping noise words in SQL Server 2005 full text indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469516/dropping-noise-words-in-sql-server-2005-full-text-indexing)