# SQL Server Full Text Search not working for me

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, contains

I have problem with Full Text Search in SQL Server.
My query:

```
Select [Name] From [POI] Where Contains([Name],  N'"bank of*"');
```

Query returns no rows.
But table has several rows that contains "bank of ..."
When I delete the word "of" everything works.
Please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in this other question [Dropping noise words in SQL Server 2005 full text indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469516/dropping-noise-words-in-sql-server-2005-full-text-indexing), noise words are not included in the indexing. "of" is a noise word, which would explain the behavior you're seeing.

See also:

[Configure and Manage Stopwords and Stoplists for Full-Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-stopwords-and-stoplists-for-full-text-search)

[Noise/Stop Words in SQL Server](http://mssqltipsandtricks.blogspot.com/2012/07/noisestop-words-in-sql-server.html)

[SQL Server: no search results caused by noise words](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135062/sql-server-no-search-results-caused-by-noise-words)

Which includes the suggestion

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON table
   SET STOPLIST OFF;
```