# Full text search not working - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server. I have the following table which I would like to perform a full text search.

```
CREATE TABLE CSWAPDB.dbo.Search 
(
    Id int IDENTITY,
    Content varchar(250) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Search_Id 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This is the full text search catalog:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG SearchContent;

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX 
    ON dbo.Search (content language 1033)
    KEY INDEX PK_Search_Id
    ON SearchContent
    WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO;
```

Inserted some data:

```
insert into search values('How are you ');
```

This search query not rerunning any result:

```
select * 
from Search 
where contains(Content, 'How');
```

The only output that I get is this warning message:

> Informational: The full-text search condition contained noise word(s)

Any idea what is wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: The error is clear. `How` is considered a noise word. You should try a better example. Words like `the`, `this`, `me` or ... all three words in your example  appear in almost every phrase and document, so they aren't useful in a full-text-search query.

Comment: Why 'How' is a noise ward ? I also have tested this with other options. Same warning message.

Comment: A quick google will explain a noise word.

Comment: Hi Dale, How can I update the noise words ?

Comment: Hi angus, I saw this post which is quite similar to your effort here (modifying a noise word list), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815415/sql-server-full-text-search-not-working-for-me?rq=1.

Comment: @angus I explained why that's a noise word. Because it can be found in almost every phrase and document, so it's statistically useless. FTS search engines work by eliminating noise words, stemming the rest of the words and indexing the stems.

Comment: @angus that said, FTS is very well documented. You can create your own stopwords and stoplists, and even specify a custom stoplist for each FTS index. That's probably better than changing the stoplists for the entire server. Ccheck [Configure and Manage Stopwords and Stoplists for Full-Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-stopwords-and-stoplists-for-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thank you Patrick and Panagiotis. I will check the links.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from Search where Content like '%How%'
```

Above query should give you the results you are expecting

Comment: This, however, won't be SARGable and would pick up other things like `'I like this, however, it's still blue'` and `'Howard the Duck'`; which is unlikely desired.

Comment: Thank you Riyas but I don't want to use LIKE. The all propose is to use full text search

Comment: The whole point of using full-text search is to handle *and* accelerate cases that `like` can't handle at all.